# error_reporting() has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: codeigniter, hosting, php

I made a project in the codeigniter framework and uploaded it to a host, the hoster said the site was filling the logfiles of the server pretty fast.

So I checked the error log and for every request i get:

```
error_reporting() has been disabled for security reasons /index.php on line 36
set_error_handler() has been disabled for security reasons /system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 72
```

I asked the host if he could turn on these options because codeigniter needs them for its error handling, but they replied with that i will have to edit my code to disable these functions on their server.

I don't want to edit core files of codeigniter, and i don't really get why it is disabled. Do any of you know an easy solution to fix this error, or some arguments to tell the hoster to change this setting for me?

Comment: You should really change hoster because disabling set_error_handler() is ridiculous. I, for example, use this function for converting errors to exceptions.

Comment: You can't. The easy fix, is editing codeigniter core files, by disable the error_reporting, and set_error_handler in the index.php and CodeIgniter.php

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the `error_reporting` feature may be disabled by a web host is to prevent faulty PHP programs from outputting crash messages to the end user that could be used by a hacker to work out how to gain access to the server. PHP crash messages contain a number of details that may be useful to hackers, including directory paths and information about the framework software being used.

It is generally considered good practice to disable error reporting for a production site, so that these messages to not get shown to end users. Switch it on for development, and off for production.

This explains why your host has disabled it.

As for how to prevent the "error reporting disabled" messages going into the log: Well, unfortunately, you can't, unless you edit the code to remove the references to `error_reporting`.

The CodeIgniter manual contains this page: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html

On this page, it states that the `error_reporting` code is in `index.php`, and they encourage you to edit it to stop it reporting errors once your code is in production.

In other words, CodeIgniter says: "please do change this". So don't worry about not wanting to change the core files (`index.php` isn't really a core file anyway).

Comment: I get why you don't want to show errors on a live site, thats why i check on what environment i am. If it is live site i set it to error_reporting(0); But this still produces this error in the logs, so i have to completely remove the environment code in index.php.

This is not a big problem if you aks me, but the other error comes from /system/core/CodeIgniter.php. This is a core file of codeigniter. And if i remove this every php error gives a 500 server error, not very pretty if you aks me.

Comment: @Bjorn -- hmmm, well, I guess the other commenters are right; it sounds like it's time for you to find a better web host.

Comment: It is generally considered **awful** practice to disable error reporting for a production site. On production error_reporting should have the same value with development server